# Shiny DownloadHandler not working on server

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I'm new here and I don't have much experience with Shiny Apps (or apps,websites and servers in general). My app works (also on the server). Only the download button to generate a report and save files on the server (a copy of the report and an excel file). I have also tried to copy the report to a tempfile. But that does not work for  me either. Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this?
The app is stored on the following path: /data/web/www/vhost/myapp.com/

I want to save the copy of the report in a subfolder (/data/web/www/vhost/myapp.com/reports) and the datasets in another subfolder (/data/web/www/vhost/myapp.com/datasets). Locally, I was able to achieve this with setwd.

```
output$dokumentationsbericht <- downloadHandler(
filename = function(){paste("Bericht_", input$skz, "_", input$monat, ".pdf", sep='')},    
content = function(file) {
cat(c(report_yaml, sep="\n"),
c(überschrift2, sep="\n"),
c(print({paste("_**Name des SQM: **_", input$sqm)}), sep="\n"),
          
c(überschrift3, sep="\n"),
c(print(pandoc.table.return(data(), style="multiline", split.tables=170)), sep="\n"),
c(newPage, sep="\n"),
c(überschrift4, sep="\n"),
c("_**Welche inhaltlichen Schwerpunkte wurden in diesem Monat gesetzt?**_", sep="\n"), 
        
sep="\n", file= paste("Bericht_", input$skz, "_", input$monat, ".Rmd", sep=''))
      
report_path <- tempfile(fileext = ".Rmd")
file.copy(paste("Bericht_", input$skz, "_", input$monat, ".Rmd", sep=''), report_path, overwrite = TRUE)
        
rmarkdown::render(report_path, 
output_file = file,
envir = new.env(parent = globalenv()))
})
```

Comment: Your code does not resemble an entire shiny app. Try to use absolute file paths instead of `setwd` to access files.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried it and found that apparently the path is not read correctly. The backslash is always converted to an underscore.. I know that I have to enter two backslashes to get one. But the result is then two underscores. I also tried forewardslashes. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

- `cat` only prints the content but does not assign it to a variable (Try to test `cat("foo") -> foo)`
- I recommend to use templates e.g. `stringr::str_glue`
- Argument `content` of function `downloadHandler` is a function with an argument `file`. The function then will write contents to a filepath which shiny sets in the `file` variable

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

report_yaml <- "Test: foo"
überschrift2 <- "Title"
input <- list(
  skz = "foo",
  monat = "Jan",
  sqm = "bar"
)

template <- "
{report_yaml}

{überschrift2}
Name des SQM: {input$sqm}
"

output$dokumentationsbericht <- downloadHandler(
  filename = function(){paste("Bericht_", input$skz, "_", input$monat, ".pdf", sep='')},    
  content = function(file) {
    str_glue(template) %>%
      write_file(file)
  }
)
```

Comment: The downloadhandler with cat works locally so that I can download a pdf. But you think cat doesn't work on my server? Your code didn't work for me unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry I've overseen the `file` argument of cat. Since the file name will be determined by Shiny (and changed over time and does not contain words like Bericht_) calling the function provided at `content`, you should write `cat("foo", file = file)` instead.

Comment: My code is meant as an inspiration and is not designed as a fully self contained shiny app

Comment: cat isn't the problem. It creates a Rmd-file as it is supposed to. I read that sometimes you have to copy the file into the tempfile. I tried it. And my file appears in the tempfile.. but I cannot access the folder. So maybe thats the problem?! How can I change that?

Comment: Does the user running the shiny app (you, shiny-server, etc.) has write permission to that directory?

Comment: It's the first time I am doing something like this. So please excuse my when i try to explain things in such a simple and strange way.. I'm a User and I have the permission to work in the directions where the App is hostet (/data/web/www/vhost/..). I also can open the temp directions (/tmp) where the tempfiles are stored and create my own subfolder. But tempfiles() crates already a subfolder in tmp (something like this /tmp/Rtempfz). However, I cannot access this subfolder. It says (i use fillezilla) the owner is shiny shiny..

Comment: Are you using shiny-server for deployment? This indeed runs the app as the user shiny. So both the shiny server user, and you want to have access to the tmp directories and their files? If you are root on the system, you can always access every file. Usually, you should have at least read permissions to these files.

Comment: I use a shiny Server for deployment. I do have a Shell access and allegedly i can access as root. So I could theoretical access those files. At this point i have three follow up question.. 1. Are files stored permanently in these tempfile folders? 2. Should the r markdown command work even thought i cannot access the tempfile? 3. When I can copy the file to tempfiles why isn't is possible to copy it to a subfolder where my app runs (/data/.../vhost/myapp/reports)? Do I simply type the directory wrong? How should the directory in my R Code look like?

Comment: 1. Everything inside `/tmp` will usually be removed after a reboot, because it is mounted into memory by default (depends on the system. However, tmp means temporary) 2. If the r markdown command is executed by the shiny user you do not need to have access to it as well.

Comment: 3. If you just want the user to download any file at your server you can just do `shiny::downloadHandler(filename = "foo.txt", content = function(file) { "/some/path/foo.txt" %>% readr::read_file() %>% readr::write_file(file)}`

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try this when i am back home. Have a nice weekend!!